# How to access current langcode in theme?

Tags: i18n-l10n

I use Integrity theme and want to make the slider images i18n aware.

I want to get the current langcode in the

```
function _integrity_get_home_block_contents
```

Previously it worked like this:

```
   global $language;
   $lang_id = $language->language;
```

What do I do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to do the same in Drupal 8:

```
$language = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage();
// Will return "en".
$shortcode = $language->getId());
// Will return "English".
$language_name = $language->getName();
```

Read more [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Language!LanguageManagerInterface.php/function/LanguageManagerInterface%3A%3AgetCurrentLanguage/8).